# Is my proof valid for: If $A-B \subseteq C$ and $A \not \subseteq C,$ then $A \cap B \not = \emptyset$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just starting to learn proofs and could use some feedback:

Statement:  Let A, B, and C be nonempty sets.  If $A-B \subseteq C$ and $A \not \subseteq C,$ then $A \cap B \not = \emptyset$.

Proof:  Since $A \not \subseteq C$, there exists an $x \in A$ such that $x \not \in C.$

Since $x \not \in C$ and $A - B \subseteq C$, $x \not \in A - B$.  Since $x \in A$ and $x \not \in A - B$, $x \in B$.

Hence $x \in A \cap B$.  That is, $A \cap B \not = \emptyset.$

Thank you.

Idle Math Guy

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: It's OK, but it much simpler to use the contradiction: if $A\cap B=\varnothing$ then $A-B=A$, and immediate contradiction.

Comment: It's important to note that $-$ is the complement, and does not refer to the Minkowski difference.

Comment: A - B is set difference.  i.e.  All the elements in the set A that are not in the set B.  ${ x | (x \in A) \land (x \not \in B)}$.

Comment: @Idle Math Guy:Was your original question answered? If so, please, provide an answer and so mark your question as settled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof is a valid proof.  I do like the contradiction route that Corvus used...I think it is more concise.